# Bash - prevent script to stop execution on error

Tags: bash, error-handling, find, exec

I need to recursively find files of one type in directory. And then for each file found execute script with found file as parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /mnt/storage/content/www/html/smartsite/src/data/resource/ ! -path "*/tmp/*" -regextype posix-awk -iregex "(.*.toConv)" -exec /mnt/storage/content/www/html/smartsite/cron/VideoConvert/convert {} \;
```

It works as should, however execution stops when called script (convert) throws error. I want to prevent this and continue execution for next files found. No matter what I do, for example

```
/convert || true {} \;
```

or

```
/convert {} || true \;
```

It always throws an error "No paremeters for exec". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you explain `throws error` or provide the script? Execution of `find` shouldn't stop on `stderr` or even if the script returns an error exit code (`-exec` will just become false, which will prevent expressions after the `-exec` from executing, and cause `find` to move on to the next file. But since there are no expressions after the `-exec` in your command, this shouldn't matter)

Comment: There is ffmpeg call inside "convert" script. If ffmpeg fails, find stops searching. I wanted to prevent this and go to the next file found. So I either I neeed to make sure that "convert" script won't throw any error to stderr or add || true to find/exec to pass "true" exit code to find, even if script fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be ok:

```
convert {} \; || true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
find ... -exec bash -c "convert {} || true" ";"
```

or

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -r -0 -i convert {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that the parsing order doesn't work the way you think it does. The command:

```
find /.../resource/ ! -path "*/tmp/*" -regextype posix-awk -iregex "(.*.toConv)" -exec /.../convert || true {} \;
```

Gets parsed by the shell into two commands (separated by `||`):

```
find /.../resource/ ! -path "*/tmp/*" -regextype posix-awk -iregex "(.*.toConv)" -exec /.../convert
true {} \;
```

...and since the `\;` is part of a separate command, `find` never sees it, and complains that you didn't give it a complete `-exec` sequence. You could quote/escape the `||` so it gets passed to `find` as part of the `-exec` sequence, but that wouldn't do what you want either, because `-exec` just runs *a single command*, and passes what it's given as arguments to that command, so the convert script would get `||` and `true` as arguments...

In order to do what you're trying to do, you'd actually have to have `-exec` run another shell, and have that subshell run the convert script and `true`. This can be done, although it's a little messy, but it won't solve the actual problem either, because the actual problem isn't what you think it is.

As @BroSlow said, `find ... -exec` *does not stop* just because the command returned an error status (or output something to stderr). Something else is making `find` stop, so overriding the exit status is not going to fix the problem. You need to figure out the *actual* problemis, and attack that.